# AVCapturePhotoOutput has no member 'captureStillImageAsynchronously'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camera

I am making a custom camera app in which i can i capture my photos by takePhoto button, but there is an error in takePhoto saying AVCapturePhotoOutput has no member 'captureStillImageAsynchronously'.

**ViewController**

```
  import UIKit
  import AVFoundation
  import CoreImage

 @available(iOS 10.0, *)
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()


@IBOutlet weak var imageViewReal: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   let deviceSession = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession.init(deviceTypes: [.builtInDuoCamera, .builtInTelephotoCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .unspecified)

    for device in (deviceSession?.devices)! {


        if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front {
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device )

                if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                   captureSession.addInput(input)

                    if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput){
                    captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)

                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = .portrait

                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                        cameraView.addSubview(takePhoto)

                        previewLayer.position = CGPoint (x: self.imageViewReal.frame.width / 2, y: self.imageViewReal.frame.height / 2 )
                        previewLayer.bounds = imageViewReal.frame
                        captureSession.startRunning()

                    }
                }
            }
            catch  {
            print("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {
        buffer, Error in
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)

            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage(data : imageData!)!, nil, nil, nil)
        })
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is compatible with iOS9, use `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`'s method:

```
func captureStillImageAsynchronously(from connection: AVCaptureConnection!, 
                   completionHandler handler: ((CMSampleBuffer?, Error?) -> Void)!)
```

If your app begins from iOS10, you should use `AVCapturePhotoOutput`'s method:

```
open func capturePhoto(with settings: AVCapturePhotoSettings, delegate: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)
```

So,`var sessionOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()` should be `var sessionOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()`.

Have a nice try.

Comment: Drawin  thanx for your effort but i am also getting error at line#54 `cameraView.addSubview(takePhoto)` errorr: `cannot convert the value of type Any to UIview`

Comment: Drawin thanx for your effort but i am also getting error at line#54 cameraView.addSubview(takePhoto) errorr: cannot convert the value of type Any to UIview